# .htaccess multiple rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a .htaccess rewrite rule that will redirect all urls containing `/ws` to the `/ws/index.php` eg. www.domain.com/ws/controller/function

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ws/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i'm looking to add another redirect, just the same, for all request that contain /email/ so www.domain.com/email/controller/function will redirect to the /email/index.php.

my full .htaccess looks like the code below but it seems the /email/ never gets called.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /ws/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /email/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've tried adding ^/email to the `RewriteRule` conditional but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are the /email/ URLs directed anywhere else or just not at all?

Comment: no, the idea is any www.domain.com/email/x/y/z to go to /email/index.php

Comment: it appears when i try a /ws url it goes straight to the email rewrite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ws/(.*)$ ws/index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^email/(.*)$ email/index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks but www.domain.com/ws/x/y/z still goes through to /email/ instead of /ws/

Comment: yes you're correct my mistake - i was running `$params = explode( "/", $_GET['url'] );` on the url which caused the index to shift down one which, is better. Many thanks!